# Numpy array with different data types

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

We both know that: "Numpy array is multidimensional array of objects of all the same type"

However, I could create a Numpy array that contains different data types as example below. Can anyone give an explain, how it could be.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([('a',1),('b',2)],dtype=[('alpha','U11'),('num','i8')])
print(a[0][1]+1)
print(len(a[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Comment: print `a`, and its `shape`. And index by fild name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are numpy records:

- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Numpy provides two data structures, the homogeneous arrays and the structured (aka *record*) arrays. The latter one, what you just stumbled across, is a structure that not only allows you to have different data types (float, int, str, etc.) but also provides handy methods to access them, through labels for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Numpy: it's called **Structured arrays**

Please read more here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

P/S: thanks Brandt